I'm looking fSSearch bar look for partial matches including letters and special characters
really finding it hard to obtain a script that does this. I've created a spreadsheet that has a data entry form 'User Form' referring to another sheet that is where the data is submitted to 'Database' row 3 is my 'job id' however this isn't always just numbers (eg. 111499B or DCWP3P00045 etc. ) is there away to change the script so when the script runs it searches row 3 for the closest job id (not necessarily an exact match) or at least the letters, numbers and special characters. Below is the script I currently have which is fine to find 111499 (if that's the number in row 3) however it won't find 111499 if a letter is added.
//Function to Search the record
function searchRecord() {
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("User Form"); //declare a variable and set with the User Form reference
  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Database"); ////declare a variable and set the reference with the Database worksheet
    
  var str=shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var values=datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from the used range and assigning it to values variable
  var valuesFound=false; //variable to store boolean value
  
  for (var i=3; i<values.length; i++) 
    {
    var rowValue=values[i]; //declare a variable and storing the value
   
    //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[3]==str){

        
      shUserForm.getRange("C7").setValue(rowValue[0]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C10").setValue(rowValue[1]);
      shUserForm.getRange("D10").setValue(rowValue[2]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C13").setValue(rowValue[3]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C16").setValue(rowValue[4]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C19").setValue(rowValue[5]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C22").setValue(rowValue[6]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C25").setValue(rowValue[7]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C28").setValue(rowValue[8]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("E28").setValue(rowValue[9]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C30").setValue(rowValue[10]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("E30").setValue(rowValue[11]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C33").setValue(rowValue[12]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("E33").setValue(rowValue[13]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C36").setValue(rowValue[14]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("E36").setValue(rowValue[15]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C39").setValue(rowValue[16]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("B44").setValue(rowValue[17]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C44").setValue(rowValue[18]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("D44").setValue(rowValue[19]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("E44").setValue(rowValue[20]) ;
      valuesFound=true;
      return; //come out from the search function
      
  }
    }

if(valuesFound==false){
  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the alert funcion
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("no record found!");
 }

}


Use String.match(), like this:
function searchRecord() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const userSheet = ss.getSheetByName('User Form');
  const key = new RegExp(userSheet.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue().trim(), 'i');
  const rangeList = userSheet.getRangeList(['C7', 'C10', 'D10', 'C13', 'C16', 'C19', 'C22', 'C25', 'C28', 'E28', 'C30', 'E30', 'C33', 'E33', 'C36', 'E36', 'C39', 'B44', 'C44', 'D44', 'E44',]);
  const data = ss.getSheetByName('Database').getDataRange().getValues();
  const match = data.find(row => String(row[3]).match(key));
  if (match) {
    rangeList.getRanges().forEach((range, index) => range.setValue(match[index + 3]));
  } else {
    ss.toast(`Cannot find a match for '${key}'.`);
  }
}

In the event the search keys may contain regex special characters, add code to escape those characters. See Regular expressions, String.match() and RangeList.

thanks so much, so do I just use this string match and not the other code? When I add it says 'The data you entered in cell C7 violates the data validation rules set on this cell' currently I have it set to bring up a calendar on double click - 'User Form'!C7,'User Form'!C10,'User Form'!C36,'User Form'!E36 - criteria 'Is valid date'

The code in the question should completely replace the code you show in the question. "When I add it says 'The data you entered in cell C7 violates the data validation rules" — that is not related to the question you asked. Remove the data validation rule for debugging.
